# time interval after which analytics server is updated

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am creating a report, in which i have to show the number of sessions, users and registrations that have occurred today in a live feed. I see that the ga dashboard is updated only till 7 am in the morning although its 10:41 am right now. Can I know after what time interval does the analytics server is updated? I am using core analytics api to fetch the data as of now, if any other api suits my requirements do suggest.

Comment: For the behaviour tab the analytics gets updated in 4-12 hrs depending on the number of hits u hv in your site... If your site has a large number of simultaneous user access, thn the reporting will tak more time else it takes 4-6 hrs normally

Comment: I have access to the real time reporting api, that is I can access the instantaneous data. Is their any way where I can know how many users, sessions and registrations have occurrd today. As the report is a live feed, I need to update it every minute.

Comment: Sry i dnt think its possible real time update is the only instantaneous analytics available.... You'll hv to show the previous days analysis till it gets sync...

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6083694

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency

Comment: Thanks @Matt the article was very informative. :) Also I wanted to know when I am requesting the data to be sorted by hours ie. using ga:hours its shows results from 00 to 23 hr, Is the data being provided in GMT format. If not, is there any way to change it using the api?

Comment: I believe that everything is in the [timezone of the view](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#timezone) if you know that you should be able to convert it to GMT, most languages have time conversion libraries -- [python datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).